# Cannot sort arrays using unwind or reduce mongodb aggregation pipline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having a problem sorting an array in a mongodb aggregation pipeline. I couldn't find an answer in stackoverflow so am posting my problem

I have some data in mongodb which has this structure

```
{ 
      testOne:{ scores:[1, 5, 8]},
      testTwo:{scores:[3, 4, 5]},
      testThree:{scores:[9,0,1]},
      ........
      testFifty:{scores:[0,8,1]}
}
```

Basically a series of many tests and the scores from those tests (this is a simplified example to illustrate the problem).

After a few hours banging my head against a wall I found I could only unwind two arrays, any more and no data was returned.

So I couldn't unwind all my arrays and group to get arrays of each test scores from the db

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        {$unwind: '$testOne.scores'},
        {$unwind: '$testTwo.scores'},
        {$unwind: '$testThree.scores'},
        {$group:{
            _id: {},
           concatTestOne: { $push: "$testOne.scores"},
           concatTestTwo: { $push: "$testTwo.scores"},
           concatTestThree: { $push: "$testThree.scores"}
    }
}
```

To my frustration , even if I just did one unwind the resulting array did not sort properly see below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        {$unwind: '$testOne.scores'},
        {$group:{
            _id: {},
           concatTestOne: { $push: "$testOne.scores"}
        }
    {$sort:{concatTestOne: 1}},
}
```

The result was [1,5,8,3,4,5,....,9,0,1]. No sorting

So to get all the tests scores I used  reduce to flatten the nested arrays resulting from the grouping stage with no 'unwinding' e.g.:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        {$group:{
            _id: {},
            concatTestOne: { $push: "$testOne.scores"}
        },
    {$addFields:{

        testOneScores:  {$reduce: {
        input: "$concatTestOne",
        initialValue: [ ],
        in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
    }
}
```

Once again the resulting arrays do not sort. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. The arrays are large (length approx 3500) is it just mongoDB aggregation doesn't handle large arrays ?

Many thanks for any comments I have spent a lot of time trying to sort my arrays and noting works so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, this is your needed query, otherwise please update your sample output.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$testOne.scores'},
    {$unwind: '$testTwo.scores'},
    {$unwind: '$testThree.scores'},
    {"$sort" : {"testOne.scores" : -1,"testTwo.scores" : -1,"testThree.scores" : -1}},
    {$group:{
        _id: {},
       concatTestOne: { $addToSet: "$testOne.scores"},
       concatTestTwo: { $addToSet: "$testTwo.scores"},
       concatTestThree: { $addToSet: "$testThree.scores"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I try to unwind more than two of the arrays the data returned is null.  I think unwinding two arrays is the limit that mongoDB can do. In any case when I just did a test and  used unwind on one array , the sort had no effect. A few of things if you could answer, I am not sure why you put $sort in double quotes, is that the correct syntax (my code errors when I do that); second am I correct that there is a limit on how many arrays you can unwind , third does this code work OK fro you.

Comment: Yes this is working fine for me.
i'm getting this output

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {},
    "concatTestOne" : [ 
        1.0, 
        5.0, 
        8.0
    ],
    "concatTestTwo" : [ 
        3.0, 
        4.0, 
        5.0
    ],
    "concatTestThree" : [ 
        0.0, 
        1.0, 
        9.0
    ],
    "concatTestFifty" : [ 
        0.0, 
        1.0, 
        8.0
    ]
}

Comment: and there is no limitation for unwind if you using more it will take some times that's it.

Comment: and i'm using mongo shell you can use anything with double quotes or without, anyway both are working fine. that's not a problem.

Comment: and my query is query
db.col.aggregate([
        {"$unwind": '$testOne.scores'},{"$unwind": '$testTwo.scores'},{"$unwind": '$testThree.scores'},{"$unwind": '$testFifty.scores'},
        {"$sort" : {"testOne.scores" : -1,"testTwo.scores" : -1,"testThree.scores" : -1,"testFifty.scores" : -1}},
        {"$group":{
            "_id": {},"concatTestOne": { "$addToSet": "$testOne.scores"},"concatTestTwo": { "$addToSet": "$testTwo.scores"},"concatTestThree": { "$addToSet": "$testThree.scores"},"concatTestFifty": { "$addToSet": "$testFifty.scores"}
            }
        }
])

Comment: Thanks . I'm not sure what my problem is but thanks for taking time to answer my questions.

Comment: upgrade your MongoDB version, maybe  its happened some versioning problem